# Pandas get previous row of time series with multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a DataFrame with two columns in the index -- one is a label, the other is a time series period. I want to get the previous row for each row in the time series. But I can't use DataFrame.shift() because there's 2 columns in the index, and the shift is mixing up the labels.

```
#Desired behavior: each 'x' row needs its prev value, each 'y' row needs
#its prev value, etc. DON'T put the 'y' row's prev value on the 'x' row.
#Have to respect both columns on the index when shifting.
x = pandas.DataFrame({ 'label' : [ 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z' ], 
     'period' : [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ],
     'value' : [ '1st x', '1st y', '1st z', '2nd x', '2nd y', '2nd z', '3rd x', '3rd y', '3rd z' ]})
x.set_index(['label', 'period'], inplace=True)

#That looks like:
>>> x
             value
label period       
x     1       1st x
y     1       1st y
z     1       1st z
x     2       2nd x
y     2       2nd y
z     2       2nd z
x     3       3rd x
y     3       3rd y
z     3       3rd z

#I can't use x.shift(1) because that mixes the 'x' and 'y' values:
>>> x.shift(1)
              value
label period       
x     1         NaN
y     1       1st x ###WRONG! should be NaN
z     1       1st y ###WRONG! Should be Nan
x     2       1st z  ###WRONG!!! This should be "1st x'
y     2       2nd x  ###Wrong!! Should be '1st y'
z     2       2nd y ###Wrong!! Should be '1st z'
x     3       2nd z  ###Wrong!! Should be '2nd x'
y     3       3rd x  #WRONG! should be '2nd y'
z     3       3rd y #WRONG! should be '2nd z'
```

How can I get the correct prev row for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `groupby` by the first index level then `shift` works as desired:

```
In [42]:
x.groupby(level='label').shift()

Out[42]:
              value
label period       
x     1         NaN
y     1         NaN
z     1         NaN
x     2       1st x
y     2       1st y
z     2       1st z
x     3       2nd x
y     3       2nd y
z     3       2nd z
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you wanted it in a more 'readable' format, you could use the `DataFrame.unstack`

```
unstacked = df.unstack(level=0)
changes = unstacked.diff()
```

Which for data like:

```
label period  value    
x     1       1
y     1       0
z     1       3
x     2       2
y     2       1
z     2       2
x     3       1
y     3       0
z     3       0
```

Produces:

```
    value
label   x   y   z
period          
1   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   1.0     1.0     -1.0
3   -1.0    -1.0    -2.0
```